# Functions and arguments in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, arguments, tuples

I'm trying to construct a function which will calculate the mean of given numbers. Numbers can be either in tuple format: `(1, 2, 3)` or in list format: `[1, 2, 3]`.

Now I have came up with this:

```
def get_mean(*arg):
   for x in arg:           ### Calculating sum
      sum = float(sum) + x
   count = len(arg)
   mean = float(sum) / int(count)
   return mean
```

Then if I try to call this function with following attributes:

```
print get_mean(1, 2, 3)
```

Output will be: `2.0`
But then:

```
print get_mean[1, 2, 3]
```

outputs an error: `TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Why is this so?

Comment: `variable[x]` is for property access while `variable(x)` is for function calls. For your second case you want `get_mean([1,2,3])`

Comment: get_mean[...] is interpreted list indexing and get_mean is not a list, it is a function. Try get_mean([1,2,3]) as a first step

Comment: but the function is defined in right way, huh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your passing arguments with the wrong syntax, *you missed the brackets*:

```
print get_mean[1, 2, 3]
```

However you'd encounter a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'list'` if you use this, *since `args` is `[[1, 2, 3]]`* :

```
print get_mean([1, 2, 3])
```

Therefore you need to unpack the list, So simply use the `*` operator

```
print get_mean(1, 2, 3)
print get_mean(*[1, 2, 3])
#2.0
#2.0
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for correction. I did what you said and got it working. Still newbie but learning, haha :)